# Prove the existence of a language L over the alphabet Σ = {1} such that L ∌ RE and L ∌ CoRE

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I attempted to create a language $L_1$ = {$<M>| L(M) = 1^*$} and prove using a reduction that $L_1$ ∌ RE and $L_1$ ∌ CoRE by showing that $HP ≤ L_1$ and $\overline{HP}$ $≤ L_1$.
But my instructor said this isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both reductions look fine and are easy to come up with. You need to ask your instructor what is wrong with your suggested reductions.

A reduction from $HP$ to $L_1$ operates as follows. Given input $\langle M, w\rangle$, the reduction outputs $\langle T\rangle$, where $T$ is a machine that rejects every input not of the form $1^*$, and for every input $x$ of the form $1^*$, it simulates the run of $M$ on $w$, and accepts $x$ only when $M$ halts on $w$.

Then, a reduction from $\overline{HP}$ to $L_1$ operates as follows. Given input $\langle M, w\rangle$, the reduction outputs $\langle T\rangle$, where $T$ is a machine that operates as follows. On input $x$ for $T$, $T$ simulates the run of $M$ on $w$ for $|x|$ steps. If within the simulation, $M$ does not reach $q_{acc}$ or $q_{rej}$, then $T$ accepts $x$. Otherwise, $T$ rejects $x$.

I leave correctness to you, and note that both reductions are valid when $T$ is a machine over an unary alphabet $\Sigma = \{ 1\}$. I think one of your suggested reduction assumes that the alphabet of $T$ is not unary, and I suspect it is the one from $\overline{HP}$, but I cannot tell for sure without seeing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your language is neither in RE nor in co-RE, and the reductions you have mentioned prove this. However, it is unclear to me whether your language is using only the alphabet $\{1\}$. This depends on how your coding of TMs which underlies $\langle \cdot \rangle$ works. To the extent that you have a concrete definition of $\langle \cdot \rangle$ in play, I'd guess that it uses more symbols than just $1$ (unless you enjoy suffering).

Your instructor may want you to add some argument over why we can just use $\{1\}$ as alphabet, since we only care about computability here.